# Possible to change the hardware cursor in SFML?

Tags: sfml

Is SFML capable of changing the hardware cursor, i.e. replacing the OS cursor with a custom image? Moving a sprite around is not really satisfying as responsiveness decreases with framerate.

Answer (score 1):

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"Demo");
window.ShowMouseCursor(false);
```

Then you can set the position of a sprite to wherever the mouse is!